# Get number of matches between two integer lists in F#

Tags: list, f#, c#-to-f#

I have two lists of integers (1's and 0's here, but could be any integer):

```
List1 : [1; 1; 1; 1]
List2 : [0; 0; 1; 0]
```

I want to count the number of matches in value and position between the two lists. So, in this case, there is only one match, at the 3rd position.

In C# I would solve this using a for-loop, like this:

```
int matches = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    if (list1[i] == list2[i])
        matches++;
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it in F#.

Comment: `List.zip`, `List.map` then `List.sum`...

Comment: btw: I see two matches `0,1` in the middle - or do you want something else?

Comment: @Carsten Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
let l1 = [1; 0; 1; 1];;                                                                               
let l2 = [0; 0; 1; 0];;                                                                               

let sumMatches ns ms = 
   List.zip ns ms 
   |> List.map (fun (n,m) -> if n=m then 1 else 0) 
   |> List.sum

> sumMatches l1 l2;;                                                               
val it : int = 2
```

---

here is an alternative with `filter` and `length`:

```
let sumMatches ns ms = 
   List.zip ns ms 
   |> List.filter (fun (n,m) -> n=m) 
   |> List.length
```

---

#### remark

If you have very large lists then you should

- use `Seq.` instead of `List.` (as the `List` modules functions will create intermediary lists)
- use `Seq.map2` as Lee proposed

as in this variant:

```
let sumMatches ns ms = 
   Seq.map2 (fun n m -> if n = m then 1 else 0) ns ms 
   |> Seq.sum
```

if you really need speed also then you should probably just do exactly as you would in C# (use a `for` loop and an mutable counter)

But usually this is no big deal.

Comment: Nice! Could you please explain what do the names of the arguments (ns and ms) stand for? Is it some kind of convention? Thanks.

Comment: FYI you can use `List.map2` instead of `zip` followed by `map`.

Comment: the suffix `s` is usually used if you have lists or sequences, ... (because plural) - and I wanted two variables standing for numbers ... so `n` and `m`

Comment: @Lee I know but I find `zip` for itself quite useful and I think you see more of the workings this way

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way - used List.fold2:

```
let l1 = [1; 0; 1; 1]                                                                             
let l2 = [0; 0; 1; 0]

let sumMatches ns ms = List.fold2 (fun acc n m -> acc + if n = m then 1 else 0) 0 ns ms

sumMatches l1 l2  |> printfn "Count = %i"
```

Print:

```
Count = 2
```

Link:   https://dotnetfiddle.net/pe9fOY